$\left |\int _{X} log(|f|)d\mu \right | < \infty$ if $\int_{X} |f| d\mu <\infty $?
Is the following true?:
Assume that $\mu$ is any positive measure with $\mu (X)=1$ and that, if $E_{0}=\left \{ x\in X :|f(x)|=0 \right \}$, we have $\mu (E_{0})=0$. Then
$$\left |\int _{X} log(|f|)d\mu \right | < \infty \Leftarrow \int_{X} |f| d\mu < \infty.$$
I was trying to use the following sets $E_{1}=\left \{ x\in X: |f(x)|\geq 1 \right \}$ and $F=\left \{ x\in X: 0<|f(x)|< 1 \right \}.$ Then we have
$$
\left |\int _{X} log(|f|)d\mu \right | = \left |\int_{E_{0}}log(|f|)d\mu + \int_{E_{1}}log(|f|)d\mu + \int_{F}log|f|d\mu \right | \\ \le \int_{E_{1}}|f|d\mu +\left 
|\int_{F}log|f|d\mu \right |.
$$
If I would be able to determine that $\left |\int_{F}log|f|d\mu \right | <\infty$ I would be done. I have the suspicion that it is true since $\left |\int_{[0,1]}log(x)dx \right | < \infty$. But how can I do this with $f$? Thanks in advance for any help.

Let $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ on $(0,1)$. Then the integral of the $\log |f|$ diverges.

Apologies, my answer had a flaw. I have deleted it accordingly.

The integral may diverge for two reasons. The first one concerns the measure by which we integrate. If the measure is large, the integral may also be large (like $\int_{\mathbb{R}}1 \,\mathrm{d}\lambda$ ). In other words, the domain is large (in terms of measure $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=\infty$) and even though the function we are integrating is small, the integral is large. This problem does not arise here because the measure is finite. However, there is second reason why the integral may diverge and (informally) it is the size of the function, i.e. the function is large vertically. This problem may occur here. The logartm function becomes large near zero. This reasoning leads to a (potential) counterexample. The function $e^{-1/x^2}$ is often enough (in terms of measure) close to zero. Hence, the integral of $\ln e^{-1/x^2}$ becomes divergent.
